# Adding a dynamic attribute name to a selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this:

```
g.append(function(d) {
  return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", d.shape);
})
```

Where `d.shape` can be `circle` or `polygon`. Now depending on the shape, I would like to add an attribute. For circle:

```
.attr('r', 12)
```

For polygon:

```
.attr('points', '05,30 15,10 25,30'))
```

But  I do not know how to add this variable pair attribute name/value. Is it possible? A related jsbin is [here](http://jsbin.com/eFAZABe/1).

Comment: You could simply add all attributes and leave them empty in cases where they don't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either use a selection filter for this, filtering on the nodeName property of the element:

```
d3.selectAll("top_level_selector") //or use existing selection from appending
.filter(function(d,i){
    return this.nodeName == 'circle';
})
.attr("r", 12);
```

- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter

Or possibly just check inside the attribute function for correct nodetype :

```
selection
.attr('r',function(d,i){
    if(this.nodeName =='circle'){ return 12 }
});
```

I'm not positive but I don't think this will present a problem when it tries to assign an "r" attribute of undefined to the non-circle elements (and so on for 'points' on circle, etc).